# typescript type from string values from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

The object with values as array of strings:

```
const STUFF = {
  abc: ["string_1", "string_2"],
  def: ["string_3", "string_4"],
  xyz: ["string_1", "string_2", "string_4"],
}
```

how to define a type that allows only values from these arrays?

```
type StuffStr = "string_1" | "string_2" | "string_3" | "string_4";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a `const` assertion on `STUFF`, it becomes a matter of indexing `typeof STUFF`.

```
const STUFF = {
  abc: ["string_1", "string_2"],
  def: ["string_3", "string_4"],
  xyz: ["string_1", "string_2", "string_4"],
} as const;

type StuffStr = typeof STUFF[keyof typeof STUFF][number];
// type StuffStr = "string_1" | "string_2" | "string_3" | "string_4"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygFQKoDEUwLwwN4CgYwCGARsAFwwDaARNAE4CWYA5gPoCM1ANDLVIy1YAmagF0u+GABMApgDMKNekzYBmbr2WCALGIkEAHgE8AXor4C2nHhZXCNtnXtwBfIhBihIUANy5cUEYADjLwUACucnJw-JgwgSEgcvDIaJQA1jJGSfHBMjmIqCiilGDhALbEMnSiPkA)

Comment: does not seem to work, the type is still a generic string

Comment: I have added a playground link. The `const` assertion is necessary; you can check in your code if TypeScript is treating it as `const` by hovering over `STUFF` and seeing its type.

Comment: I think the issue is that my string values come from other consts, which I guess should also have `as const`.. but then I would not be able to create a function that uses this type to search inside the same object

Comment: @Alex Update your post with *all* the relevant code then, and why this approach would not work.

Comment: its ok, i`ve chosen a different approach, by clearly defining the types outside